# Should a disavow file specify domains or URLs?

Tags: seo, disavow-links

Should I use full domain URL like `https://www.examples.com/` or only the domain without `http`/`https` in a disavow file?

Answer (score 4):

The Google docs show both but there is a domain: instead of HTTP: when you need to disavow an entire domain. So the question that answers your question is do you need to disavow a page on a domain or the whole domain? IE you would not want to disavow the entire site for sites.google.com or the entire site of New York Times if they had spam in their comments.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en

```
 # Two pages to disavow 
http://spam.example.com/stuff/comments.html 
http://spam.example.com/stuff/paid-links.html
 
 # One domain to disavow 
domain:shadyseo.com
```

If you don't use the HTTP: or HTTPS: you should use the DOMAIN:

FYI there is currently no wildcard for usage in the disavow tool, the page I referenced is their page that is linked to which should be updated when the tool is updated.